# redirect to a page if response.redirect fails

Tags: c#

I have a `response.redirect(url)` which goes to another site.
In the event this fails, how should I redirect again to a **redirect fail** page?

1. The request is being sent from the code behind an aspx page.
2. I have an **`httpmodule`** in place. Can it be used?

Comment: The initial redirect goes to a completely different site, or just another page on your application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

response.redirect(url) tells browser to request the "url" so you can not control if this url call is failed in browser.

What you can do is do a HTTP <strike>GET</strike> HEAD to that url first to see if you get http 200 response and then do a response.redirect(url).

Comment: agreed.  If the new page is on a different server outside of the OP's control then the only way to do this is first test if that server is available then decide whether to redirect or not

Comment: Nitpick: rather than performing an HTTP GET, consider performing an HTTP HEAD instead and save yourself some bandwidth - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830435/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-on-a-server-using-c-and-the-webclient-class

Comment: @Chris - So, regardless of the client and server (normally) having completely different networks and see the web differently, a check on the server side would mean something on the client side?

Comment: @Oded: As you're attempting to point out, it is entirely possible that the server does indeed see things differently.  This could be the case if the server is locked down from making external requests or if the network it is on is configured in such a way that certain sites are blocked.  Both of which are possible and even likely.  If this is the case then this answer would utterly fail.  However, if it is sufficiently important to be able to perform this action then I'd hope the OP (and perhaps his/her boss) could cajole the net admins into allowing those outbound requests.

Comment: @Nitpick yes http head makes more sense for bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make much sense - if a redirect fails, how will the server ever find out?

A redirect tells the browser to go to a different page - if this fails, it fails on the browser and the server has no way to know about it.

Comment: Not true completely. You can catch it and redirect in the catch. I think the problem is how to tell it to redirect without "Response" because the object is null.