# check to see if URL is a download link using webclient c#

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I am reading from the history database, and for every URL read, I am downloading it and storing the data into a string. I want to be able to determine if the link is a download link, i.e. .exe or .zip for e.g. I am assuming I need to read the headers to determine this, but I don't know how to do it with WebClient. Any suggestions?

```
while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
{
    noIndex = false;

    string url = (string)sqlite_datareader["url"];

    try
    {
        if (url.Contains("http") && (!url.Contains(".pdf")) && (!url.Contains(".jpg")) && (!url.Contains("https")) && !isInBlackList(url))
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");


            String htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading the complete content behind the link, I would issue a HEAD request.

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.

Quote of http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

See these questions for C# examples

- [How to check if a file exists on a server using c# and the WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830435/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-on-a-server-using-c-and-the-webclient-class)
- [How to check if System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData is downloading a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153451/c-how-to-check-if-system-net-webclient-downloaddata-is-downloading-a-binary-fi)

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track; you'll need to examine the `ResponseHeaders` after a successful request:

```
var someType = "application/zip";
if (client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"].Contains(someType)) {
    // this was a "download link"
}
```

The tricky part will be in determining what constitutes a download link since there are so many content types possible. For example, how would you decide whether XML data is a download link or not?

Comment: That's true. Perhaps there is a way to check the size of data before download? However, seeing as I don;t have much time, .exe, .zip and .rar will suffice. Thank you

Comment: ok still, I will need to download the string or get the response stream..the reason why i want to filter out .exe etc is so that i won't need to download them. unfortunately not all links contain .exe in their URL and so i will need to see response header :/

Comment: You could try using `DownloadStringAsync()` instead. Then as soon as you have the headers you can determine what to do with the content and either cancel or allow the download to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check WebClient's [ResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders.aspx) collections to validate response file type.

Answer (score 0):

In case, anyone has the same problem, I have used an attribute in the history places.sqlite database which came in very handy!

Places.sqlite contains a table called moz_historyvisits which contains a column visit_type. According to [1], a visit_type of 7 is a *download link*. Therefore, reading this value will determine if it is a download link without reading the response header or even sending out a head method.

[1] http://www.firefoxforensics.com/research/moz_historyvisits.shtml